# build lua in visual studio, 'setfenv' cannot change environment of given object

Tags: visual-studio-2010, lua

I want to build **lua-5.1.4** with Visual Studio 2010; everything seems OK, but the following script:

```
local P = {}
P._G = _G

if _REQUIREDNAME == nil then
smartinput = P
else
_G[_REQUIREDNAME] = P
end
setfenv(1, P)
```

got the error message:

```
‘setfenv’ cannot change environment of given object
```

I got binaries from

http://sigttou.com/lua-visual-studio-2010-2#comment-209

which were also built by Visual Studio 2010.  The script works well, but when I use the project file to build the source myself, the error appears again.

What do I need to do to avoid this problem?

Comment: "when I use **the project file**"  What project file? Did you create it yourself from the Lua source downloaded from lua.org, or did you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: yeah, I create the project file myself, and also download from http://sigttou.com/lua-visual-studio-2010-2#comment-209, both of them don't work well; especially for the download one, options of project must be the same, but binaries built by myself not work, binaries downloaded from the site work well.

Comment: Hello,anybody? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you are not stuck with VS, you can try building from sources using TDM-GCC. I recently wrote a [step-by-step tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLuaInWindowsForNewbies) on Lua WIKI.